# Routing difference between GraphHopper and ORS

Tags: openstreetmap, graphhopper

I know that ORS (openrouteservice) is developed under GraphHopper routing library, but comparing those two heavy truck queries, I found the same distance but with a difference of two hours driving!

https://maps.openrouteservice.org/directions?n1=48.4184&n2=2.284057&n3=7&a=50.632786,3.059524,43.603902,1.440694&b=4a&c=0&k1=en-US&k2=km

https://graphhopper.com/maps/?point=50.635635%2C3.063008&point=43.605637%2C1.448693&locale=en-US&vehicle=truck&weighting=fastest&elevation=true&use_miles=false&layer=OpenStreetMap

I know also that the travel time is calculated for each segment by using speed-limits for different waytypes [see Travel Time Calculation] (https://github.com/GIScience/openrouteservice-docs).

If that's the reason why both queries output a different driving time is that the ORS determines different speed-limits to the ways.

Is there a way to change those speed limits before depolying my docker image so they can fit OSM?

Comment: Do the queries assume all the same parameters?  You say openrouteservice is based on GraphHopper (but it gives the longer journey time) does it factor in additional issues, like gradient/surface, that are not included in GraphHopper  for example.  Please edit the question to add more details.  You should I think give the results/differences in the question rather than relying on the links

Comment: According to [GitHub](https://github.com/GIScience/openrouteservice/), OpenRouteService was forked from [GraphHopper 0.10](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/releases/tag/0.10.0) which in turn had been released in March, 2018. Both their source code and their driving profile parameters are different. Likewise, their map data is most likely not from the same date. You can't get exactly the same result.

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58707626/routing-difference-between-graphhopper-and-ors

Comment: crosspost deleted / original post modified